# I am not able to click on dialer to perform any activity using appium

Tags: appium

I was trying to do some action in the inbuilt Phone application, and trying to press 0 key (long press) but every time when I am trying to do, facing the issue:

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Returned value cannot be converted to WebElement: {ELEMENT=1}
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'

My code

```
package mobileapp.com.example;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.TouchAction;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;

public class Call {


  AndroidDriver<WebElement> driver;


    @BeforeClass
    public void Setup() throws MalformedURLException {

        DesiredCapabilities cap= new DesiredCapabilities();
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Fever");
        cap.setCapability("platformVersion", "6.0");
        cap.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        cap.setCapability("appPackage", "com.android.dialer");
        cap.setCapability("appActivity", "com.android.dialer.DialtactsActivity");

        //driver=new AndroidDriver<WebElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap);
        driver=new AndroidDriver<WebElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap);
    }

    @Test
    public void simpleTest() {

        driver.findElement(By.id("com.android.dialer:id/floating_action_button")).click();


        WebElement ele=driver.findElement(By.id("com.android.dialer:id/zero"));


        TouchAction action=new TouchAction(driver);
        action.longPress(ele);

        ele.click();

    }

}
```

I am using Appium version 1.4.16.1  and appium java client version was 5.0.4

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that you are using very **old** appium server and **latest** java client, so your issue is caused by incompatibility of client/server versions.

Update server to the **1.7.x**

If locator is correct, it should work after update. Alternately you may use:

```
driver.pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.KEYCODE_NUMPAD_0);
```

where `driver` is instance of `AndroidDriver` class

Comment: hi facing the same issue Returned value cannot be converted to WebElement: {ELEMENT=1} Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown' , as i tried on the latest appium server also, follow the link to  check the appium logs 
https://www.sendspace.com/file/c7n2jm

please provide solution

Comment: kindly look into this and provide the solution